# How to migration HTTP POST .NET Framework to .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migration, http-post

In ASP.NET I have the following method in controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult POST()
{
  string mainJson = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  string jsonString = (myObjClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObjClass>(mainJson);
  //Do something
  return Ok();
}
```

And now I need to use this code in my ASP.NET Core project and I don't know how to use a code with webhook

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult POST([FromBody]string value)
{
  // what should I use here instead of [request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;]?

  //Do something
  return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do the following, and model binding will do other work for you:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult POST([FromBody] MyObjClass data)
{
  //Do something with data
  return Ok();
}

public class MyObjClass  
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This [Model binding JSON POSTs](http://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) article could help you to understand how it works.

Comment: i have the following question .. WebClient.DownloadData  and UploadData     i cant use this in net core have some thing like this?